# Symfony + doctrine + one-to-many relationships

Tags: php, database-design, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

I need a one-to-many relationships for my sf 1.4 + doctrine 1.2 project.
I copied the relation just like this:

```
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    contact_id:
      type: integer(4)
    username:
      type: string(255)
    password:
      type: string(255)

Phonenumber:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
  relations:
    User:
      foreignAlias: Phonenumbers
```

Then, I rebuild my schema, and generate the backend modules for User and Phonenumber.

In the Phonenumber admin panel, I can set the user by a select box with Users.
But in the User admin panel I do not have a list with the phonenumbers to allow users to select multiple phonenumbers to the user.
How can I add the many relation here?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to do it this way round as it's likely that your user will have many relations and not phonenumbers, so this keeps it all in one place....

In your **User**:

```
relations:
   Phonenumber:
     class: Phonenumber  // model name for relation
     local: id           // key in this table
     foreign: id         // key in the referenced table
     type: many          // User has MANY phonenumbers
     foreignType: one    // Phonenumber has ONE user
     alias: Phonenumber  // What a user calls Phonenumber
     foreignAlias: User  // What a Phonenumber calls User
```

Given that you're declaring the "id" for both tables instead of allowing Doctrine to create them automatically, you may need to include the "local" and "foreign"... havent tested.

Comment: I think that foreign reference needs to be 'user_id' but you've got it +1